# Javascript equivalent to PHP code

Tags: php, javascript

I need a Javascript equivalent to the following code.  I am converting a php website into a django website and on a static page I have the following:

```
<li<?if($page == "home") {?> class="active"<?}?>><a href="/home" title="Home">Home</a></li>
```

The problem is I would like to remove the php here and have the class="active" when on that page using javascript

Comment: That would be javascript you are looking at. CSS for the styling, and JS for the dynamic changes. However, I would avoid that as some browsers have JS disabled. Never rely on JS for accessibility. Only use it for enhancements.

Comment: I'll just pray && hope you'll never be able to do that with CSS.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: This would definitely be an enhancement. You are correct but I think the fear of disabled JS goes a little too far sometimes.

Comment: @WesleyMurch always play it safe.

Comment: yes I know CSS is mainly for styling, but I was curious if there was some small method added into CSS since this I feel is a common part of many webpages

Comment: @ChristopherH: Why can't you use Django template syntax? Or, if the page is *truly* static (nothing dynamic), just hard code the class right into the HTML.

Comment: This question definitely didn't deserve such harsh downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY need to do this, you can use `.addClass()` in jquery http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: How would you select the correct element to `addClass` to it?

Comment: @WesleyMurch  `.ready()` then he'd have to dig through the DOM a bit to get to menu, or simply add an id to it and target that after the page loads

Comment: I think I will just use jquery... just thought I would ask if there was some CSS hack for this

Comment: If he can "add an id" then I would assume he could add a class... I guess I don't understand. I guess you could search for the links that have `element.href === window.location.href`

Comment: @WesleyMurch - that's what I was getting at. It's a major hack, but I guess would work if it needed to

Answer (score 3):

You don't need javascript for this. You can dynamically add a class to the body tag, like so:

```
<body class="blog">
```

...and add a class to each of your links like so:

```
<a class="home" href="" >...</a>
<a class="blog" href="" >...</a>
<a class="about" href="" >...</a>
```

...and then add this rule to your css:

```
body.blog a.blog, body.home a.home, body.about a.about
{
    // Do stuff that you only want applied to the "active" page link
}
```

**The basic idea is that this only applies your 'active' styling to the element on the page with the correct match between the body tags class, and the element you want styled's class**

Comment: Please use the "Answer" box for solutions, not comments.

Comment: updated, just wanted to catch @Christopher's attention before he did the more complex solution. My apologies for the confusion

Comment: OK, but in the future don't use placeholder answers such as *"You don't need javascript for this."*.

Comment: Actually I'll upvote instead because this is a rather clever approach.

Comment: Yep, this approach is better than mine! :) +1 for you. Only problem is it's not really as dynamic as a JS solution , but it's cleaner

Comment: It's definitely not appropriate for every situation, just seemed like a good fit for this one :-)

Answer (score 1):

to get current page in js,

```
var currentpage = document.location.href
// this will return the full path e.g. http://www.home/home.html
var homepage = currentpage.search(/home.html/);

if (homepage >-1)...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS equivalent. CSS isn't that smart (yet). You can do something in JavaScript but that would be silly if you already can do it with a server side language.

**Note** The original title asked for CSS, not JavaScript. It has since been edited.

Answer (score 0):

**`CSS`** is a language for styling HTML elements.

**`PHP`** is a server-side scripting language.

There's a big difference with that. You cannot do what `CSS` can do in `PHP`, and vice versa. Imagine an artist, and an engineer.

`JavaScript` is your closest way. It's a client-side scripting language. And to do what you want to do, in jQuery:

```
$('li').addClass('active');
```

But of course, you need to post more of your code.